# Dúvida com select case

Tags: postgresql, query, select

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
select

f.no_equipe,
i.no_cbo,
count(b.tp_atend)


from

tb_equipe F,
tb_cds_prof G,
tb_cbo I,
tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual D,
tb_cds_atend_individual B

where

F.nu_ine = G.nu_ine and
G.nu_cbo_2002 = I.co_cbo_2002 and
D.co_cds_prof = G.co_seq_cds_prof and
B.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = D.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl

group by

F.no_equipe, I.no_cbo
```

Quero incluir mais dois campos:

1. `count(where b.tp_atend = 1 ou 2)`
2. `count(where b.tp_atend = 3 ou 4)`

Sei que posso fazer usando CASE, mas não estou sabendo criar o comando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você quer fazer um `COUNT` condicional, é necessário utilizar o `SUM` e dentro dele um `CASE`, caso a condição for satisfeita irá somar 1 senão somará 0.

```
select

f.no_equipe,
i.no_cbo,
count(b.tp_atend),
sum(
    CASE
        WHEN b.tp_atend IN (1, 2) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
) as count1,
sum(
    CASE
        WHEN b.tp_atend IN (3, 4) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
) as count2

from

tb_equipe F,
tb_cds_prof G,
tb_cbo I,
tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual D,
tb_cds_atend_individual B

where

F.nu_ine = G.nu_ine and
G.nu_cbo_2002 = I.co_cbo_2002 and
D.co_cds_prof = G.co_seq_cds_prof and
B.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = D.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl

group by

F.no_equipe, I.no_cbo
```

Comment: `ERRO:  função if(boolean, integer, integer) não existe`